# Why does OutputStream returned by DriveContents.getOutputStream() not act as expected?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have been playing with Google Drive API for Android and I have stumbled across a bit of a problem. In particula I am interested in App Folder fro saving and synchronizing app data across devices.
I can query if a file with certain filename exists in app folder.
I can get file via

```
driveFile = metadata.getDriveId().asDriveFile();
```

I can open file via

```
driveFile.open( mGoogleApiClient,
                DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY,
                new DownloadProgressListener() {...} )
.setResultCallback(...);
```

And in the later callback I can get OutputStream with:

```
OutputStream outputStream = dcr.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
```

But the problem is that if I try to write to that OutpustStream nothing is written to file. I have used code like that:

```
OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new      OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
try {
    writer.write("Just some strinh I want to save to Google Drive.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
Status status = dcr.getDriveContents().commit(mGoogleApiClient, null).await();
```

Using this OutputStream nothing is ever written to GoogleDrive. But if I use code from https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files#making_modifications it works as expected.

A copied snippet of that code from google for reference:

```
try {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = contents.getParcelFileDescriptor();

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor
        .getFileDescriptor());
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
    writer.write("hello world");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why does OutputStream accesible by DriveContents.getOutputStream() not work as expected? Why is it even provided? Or am I missing something?
Version of Google Play Services Library is r29.

Answer (score 0):

Close the OutputStreamWriter - writer.close() to commit the output.